# Cannot convert a .csproj to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

There is an open-source project ([Keepass](http://keepass.info/download.html)) with 3 .csproj files. When I open the main solution, it will ask me about the conversion, and it goes through the process without any problem. Except, the "KeepassLibSD" won't convert.

"The project type is not supported by this installation."
How do I determine what kind of installation do I need to convert the project?

**The said .csproj**: http://pastebin.com/y3enieZf

My about dialog shows the following packages (and information, without the kb fixes):

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50501 SP1Rel

Installed Version: Ultimate

Microsoft Office Developer Tools   01019-532-2002102-70520
Microsoft Office Developer Tools

Microsoft Visual Basic 2010   01019-532-2002102-70520
Microsoft Visual Basic 2010

Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01019-532-2002102-70520
Microsoft Visual C# 2010

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010   01019-532-2002102-70520
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

Microsoft Visual F# 2010   01019-532-2002102-70520
Microsoft Visual F# 2010

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Architecture and Modeling Tools   01019-532-2002102-70520
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Architecture and Modeling Tools

UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States and other countries.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Code Analysis Spell Checker   01019-532-2002102-70520
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer   01019-532-2002102-70520
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010   01019-532-2002102-70520
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010

Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010   
Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools   10.0.30319
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools
```

Comment: I have the "Ultimate" version with everything installed, except the SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search of internet returned this [page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/forums/forum/329221/topic/3950018).

> The Express version of Visual Studio doesn't support projects for
>   Smart Devices.

Does it help? :)

Comment: That explains a lot. I wonder if I can just delete the whole SD library. (Thanks for the answer, I couldn't find the same thread via Google.)

Comment: Haha. I was using Bing, so I am not sure about Google. Anyway, you can just unload the project to make sure stuff works, you don't need to delete it right away. :)

Comment: Well, it couldn't load that part anyway ("not compatible"). I only intend to port the desktop part of Keepass. And now it's time to port!

Answer (score 2):

```
   <PlatformFamilyName>PocketPC</PlatformFamilyName>
```

That's the problem part of the project.  PocketPC was a specification for PDAs, hand-held devices that boot Windows Mobile Classic.  The last edition of Visual Studio that still supports it is VS2008 Professional.  All support for Windows Mobile projects was removed from VS2010.

A company named Apple is largely responsible for that, you might have heard of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

[According to the KeePass forums](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/bb0e01f1), you may safely ignore the project's failure to load. The other projects don't require it to build.