# inheriting an old c# project, can't get it opened

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've inherited a C# project from a previous co-worker. This project apparently hasn't been run or anything in years. I can't even figure out which version of VS it was created with (looking at the co-workers old VM it looks like vs2008, but when I download a version of vs2008 express it tells me "the project file foo.csproj can't be opened, the project type is not supported by this installation". and solution folders are not supported in this version of visual studio). I've tried opening it in vs2008, vs2010, vs2013, vs2015 and none of it works. I'm at a loss here as to how to get this project even loaded into visual studio.

EDIT: As requested, the first 20-30 lines of the sln and csproj files:

SLN:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "BinLabel", "BinLabel\BinLabel.csproj", "{D5B787C0-B61A-48AC-81BB-E848D86F3A18}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{148F7AB7-001A-4C9A-8912-A585F2ED84BF}"
EndProject
Project("{B900F1C2-3D47-4FEC-85B3-04AAF18C3634}") = "BinLabelCab", "BinLabelCab\BinLabelCab.vddproj", "{B89E7F61-18AB-4BB9-8616-30E1E1AB9022}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {D5B787C0-B61A-48AC-81BB-E848D86F3A18}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {D5B787C0-B61A-48AC-81BB-E848D86F3A18}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {D5B787C0-B61A-48AC-81BB-E848D86F3A18}.Debug|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {D5B787C0-B61A-48AC-81BB-E848D86F3A18}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {D5B787C0-B61A-48AC-81BB-E848D86F3A18}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {D5B787C0-B61A-48AC-81BB-E848D86F3A18}.Release|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {B89E7F61-18AB-4BB9-8616-30E1E1AB9022}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug
        {B89E7F61-18AB-4BB9-8616-30E1E1AB9022}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

And the csproj:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{D5B787C0-B61A-48AC-81BB-E848D86F3A18}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>BinLabel</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>BinLabel</AssemblyName>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <PlatformFamilyName>PocketPC</PlatformFamilyName>
    <PlatformID>b2c48bd2-963d-4549-9169-1fa021dce484</PlatformID>
    <OSVersion>5.2</OSVersion>
    <DeployDirSuffix>BinLabel</DeployDirSuffix>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <NativePlatformName>Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK</NativePlatformName>
    <FormFactorID>
    </FormFactorID>
```

When I try to load it in VS2015 I get:
[image: attempting to open project in vs2015]

Clicking OK on that popup will let the sln load, but marks the other projects as "unavailable".

Comment: what is the error when opened in vs2015?  And are these the Express editions?  Is your project supported by Express?

Comment: Find the .sln file and post the visual studio version string from there.

Comment: Depending on the version/year and configuration, some express installations can only open web projects or desktop projects, but may not open both.  I've also had issues where express installs can not open WCF projects.

Comment: Find the `.sln` file if you have one and the `.csproj` file. Open them with notepad and copy the first 20-30 lines of each into your question [as a edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39666532/edit). Make sure you highlight the text and press the button that looks like `{ }` in the text editor on the website or it will strip out all the xml tags before you save your edit.

Comment: It looks like it's targetting pocketpcs, which aren't supported in Express versions [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11376748/1193647)

Comment: @Kolichikov wow, that would do it. Yeah this was for a pocketPC from ages ago, so that would make sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Kolichikov if you want to make that into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kolichikov said above in the comments:

It looks like it's targeting pocketpcs, which aren't supported in Express versions [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11376748/1193647)

Answer (score 0):

As outlined above, open the solution and right click any project that doesn't load and click Edit 'projectName'.proj

There should be "ProjectTypeGuids" section at the top of the XML
Search for them via google or check out this list I found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

The id's should tell you what type/version the project is and you can figure out what you need to open it.

Comment: As Kolichikov stated above this project looks to be targeting pocketPcs, and will only open in full versions of VS, which explains the major issue I was having. Also the latest version of VS won't open it because it's a really old version of pocketPc, so that's also a problem. Thanks for the info about figuring out what the project requires!